# How to call url uniquely which has same number of parameter from django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have an issue in django template while calling url on my anchor tag.

Here is my anchor on my template

```
<a href="{% url 'info_page' detail.slug %}">
```

I have bellow url pattern,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cars/', include([
                    url(r'^$', category_page, name=cars),
                    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', category_page, name=cars),
        ])
    ),
    url(r'^cars/', include([
                    url(r'^$', info_page_view, name='info_page'),
                    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', info_page_view, name='info_page'),
        ])
    )
]
```

Basically I would like to redirect this anchor url to my 'info_page_view' defination defined in views, 
but its actually landing it into 'category_page' defination.

I might be missing some url parameter while calling from template but not getting the exact solution for that.

As I'm calling urls by their name given,
How do I differentiate these urls and call them uniquely from template to landup in expected view. Please suggest.

Comment: urlpatterns work on the principle of... patterns matching! Imagine you are the resolver of the urls. So which patterns matches this url: `/cars/foobar/` - the 2nd or the 4th? You cant tell because they're the same. In such case it's resolved by the first one which matches. You need to have a different prefix for both the categories, eg. `cars-info/` for the second category so the match will be unique.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko: But if I'm calling url by its name given then atleast it should first check the url name and then check the urlpattens ...right. But its not happening. So according to you I need to change the urlpattern to call it uniquely. Is there any other way in which I can resolve this issue.

Comment: No, the name is there just for translating it to the url in functions like `{% url %}` or `reverse()`. The names needs to be unique, but the produced urls not - since they are just patterns, there is no way how to prevent their collisions (eg. `[0-9]` is different pattern than `\d` but they are still the same). So you can end up with a multiple routes having the same url. It's up to you to prevent that from happening, otherwise it wont work as in this case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks !! I will change my urlpattern accordingly.